# make: cl: Command not found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, console, or-tools

I'm trying to install Google OR-Tools for Java in Visual Studio 2015. When I run `make all` in the OR-Tools directory, as required, I get

```
E:\My_files\VS\BC\or-tools_VisualStudio2015-64bit_v6.4.4495>make all
cl /EHsc /MD /nologo /D_SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -nologo /O2 -DN
DEBUG -DUSE_CBC -DUSE_CLP /D__WIN32__ /Iinclude\\src\\windows 
/DGFLAGS_DLL_DECL=
 /DGFLAGS_DLL_DECLARE_FLAG= /DGFLAGS_DLL_DEFINE_FLAG= /Iinclude /I. -
DUSE_GLOP -
DUSE_BOP -c examples\\cpp\\costas_array.cc /Foobjs\\costas_array.obj
make: cl: Command not found
make: *** [objs\\costas_array.obj] Error 127
```

I read somewhere to run `vcvarsall.bat` to set variables, but there is no such file on this path

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat
```

Plus I'm supposed to run it in Native Tools Command Prompt, but I cannot find this for VS2015, only for VS2017, so I run it in Developer Command Prompt. Might this be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, I did not add C++ tools when installing Visual Studio.

`File -> New -> Project -> Visual C++` and there's the install option. Maybe it will help someone.